# Problema ao comparar strings e string sendo quebrada em duas linhas python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, comparação

Estava criando um jogo que embaralha palavras, e o usuário tem 6 tentativas pra adivinhar qual é a palavra. Vou colocar o código aqui:

```
import random

def main():
    while True:
        input('Presisone enter para sortear uma nova palavra.')
        palavra_oculta, dica = EscolhePalavra()
        palavra_embaralhada = EmbaralhaPalavra(palavra_oculta)
        palavra_embaralhada = palavra_embaralhada.lower()
        palavra_oculta = palavra_oculta.lower()
        tentativas = 6
        while tentativas != 0:
            print('\nA palavra embaralhada é: %s'%palavra_embaralhada)
            print('A dica é: %s'%dica)
            print('Você ainda tem %d tentativas.'%tentativas)
            palpite = input('Digite seu palpite: ')
            if palpite == palavra_oculta:
                print('Parabéns, você acertou!!!')
                break
            else:
                print('Ainda nao, tente novamente!')
                tentativas -= 1
        if tentativas == 0:
            print('Você perdeu! a palavra correta era %s.'%palavra_oculta)
        else:
            print('Parabéns, você acertou a palavra!!!')

def EscolhePalavra(): #Essa função está funcionando normalmente, a usei em outro jogo.
    lista_arquivos = {'Animais.txt' : 'Animal', 'Frutas.txt' : 'Fruta',
                      'Objetos.txt' : 'Objeto', 'Pessoas.txt' : 'Pesssoa',
                      'Profissões.txt' : 'Profissão'}
    arquivo_escolhido = random.choice(list(lista_arquivos.keys()))
    palavra = random.choice(open(arquivo_escolhido).readlines())
    dica = lista_arquivos[arquivo_escolhido]
    return(palavra, dica)

def EmbaralhaPalavra(palavra):
    palavra = list(palavra)
    random.shuffle(palavra)
    palavra = ''.join(palavra)
    return palavra

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Vamos aos problemas:
Primeiro, com a palavra embaralhada. Por algum motivo que ainda não sei qual, ao dar um `print` em `palavra_embaralhada`, na maioria das vezes ela fica quebrada em duas linhas. Já tentei dar um `print` nela em uma linha separada no código, mas o problema persiste.

O segundo, é que a comparação entre a `string` escrita pelo usuário armazenada na variável `palpite`, e a `palavra_oculta` quase sempre sai errado. Só consegui *acertar* uma vez. Por mais que eu digite a palavra correta, o programa considera como sendo duas *strings* diferentes. O que eu tenho que fazer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Primeiro, com a palavra embaralhada. Por algum motivo que ainda não
>   sei qual, ao dar um print em palavra_embaralhada, na maioria das vezes
>   ela fica quebrada em duas linhas. Já tentei dar um print nela em uma
>   linha separada no código, mas o problema persiste.

- O problema ocorre na função `EmbaralhaPalavra`, supondo que a variável `palavra_oculta` tenha o valor *Bar*, ao usar o [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list), o valor retornado é uma lista contendo `['B', 'a', 'r', '\n']`, e quando faz o embaralhamento com [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle), acontece o seguinte *(pode variar)*: `['a', 'B', '\n', 'r']`, ou seja, o motivo para haver *quebras de linha*, é devido a [*nova linha*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines) que é criada com o uso de `list`. Para corrigir isso, será necessário remover a nova linha antes de fazer o embaralhamento. Um modo de fazer isto é usar o método [`rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.rstrip), existem também outras maneiras.

  ```py
  def EmbaralhaPalavra(palavra):
     palavra = palavra.rstrip()
     palavra = list(palavra)
     random.shuffle(palavra)
     palavra = ''.join(palavra)
     return palavra
  ```

> O segundo, é que a comparação entre a string escrita pelo usuário
>   armazenada na variável palpite, e a palavra_oculta quase sempre sai
>   errado. Só consegui "acertar" uma vez. Por mais que eu digite a
>   palavra correta,o programa considera como sendo duas strings
>   diferentes. O que eu tenho que fazer?

- **Mesmo problema**. Agora na função `EscolhePalavra`, na linha onde abre o arquivo e lê as linhas:

  ```py
  palavra = random.choice(open(arquivo_escolhido).readlines())
  ```

  O `readlines()` retorna tudo, incluindo novas linhas, quando se faz a comparação: `if palpite == palavra_oculta..`, é comparado: `Bar` com `Bar\n`. Para resolver isso, pode-se usar a mesma solução que foi usada no primeiro problema, ou usar o método [`str.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) ao invés de `readlines()`, isso irá eliminar as *quebras de linha*.

  ```py
  def EscolhePalavra(): 
     lista_arquivos = {'Animais.txt' : 'Animal', 
                       'Frutas.txt' : 'Fruta',
                       'Objetos.txt' : 'Objeto', 
                       'Pessoas.txt' : 'Pesssoa',
                       'Profissões.txt' : 'Profissão'}
     arquivo_escolhido = random.choice(list(lista_arquivos.keys()))
     linhas = open(arquivo_escolhido).read().splitlines()
     palavra = random.choice(linhas)
     dica = lista_arquivos[arquivo_escolhido]
     return(palavra, dica)
  ```

  A comparação de *strings* no Python é *case-sensitive*, o que pode afetar o resultado do jogo, pois é comparado as letras *minúsculas* da variável `palavra_oculta` com o valor da variável `palpite`, que poderá conter letras maiúsculas, utilize também o método `lower()` em `palpite`.

Comment: Não conhecia esse `splitlines()`. Valeu pela resposta!